# cellForItem or sizeForItem not called

Tags: iglistkit

I am trying out IGListKit for the first time but i seem to have hit a brick wall early on

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    return collectionView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView)

    let updater = ListAdapterUpdater()
    let adapter = ListAdapter(updater: updater, viewController: self, workingRangeSize: 0)
    adapter.collectionView = self.collectionView

    adapter.dataSource = self
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.frame = view.bounds
}
```

And

```
extension SocialViewController: ListAdapterDataSource {

func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
    // this can be anything!
    return [ "Foo" as ListDiffable, "Bar" as ListDiffable]
}

func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any) -> ListSectionController {
    return TopNewsSectionController()
}

func emptyView(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> UIView? {
    return UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "swords"))
}
```

}

class TopNewsSectionController: ListSectionController {

```
override func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: 55)
}

override func cellForItem(at index: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionContext!.dequeueReusableCell(of: TopNewsCollectionViewCell.self, for: self, at: index)
}
```

}

but my neither cellForItem or sizeForItem is being called
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the IGListAdapterDataSource methods (objects, section controller) to make sure they are being called? I'm also assuming you put a breakpoint in sizeForItem() and cellForItem(), right? Which version of IGListKit are you using? Your setup looks fine to me. You might want to try posting this as an issue on GitHub, we're a little more active there: https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/issues/new

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare adapter as a class property rather than a method property,

```
    let updater = ListAdapterUpdater()
    let adapter = ListAdapter(updater: updater, viewController: self, workingRangeSize: 0)
    adapter.collectionView = self.collectionView
```

to

```
    lazy var adapter: ListAdapter = {
        return ListAdapter(updater: ListAdapterUpdater(), viewController: self, workingRangeSize: 0)
    }()
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `adapter.performUpdatesAnimated` or `adapter.reloadDataWithCompletion` (for the first time loading) to update

Answer (score 0):

Your `adapter` object is destroyed when `viewDidLoad` returns. Try to declare it as a property of your `ViewController`.